# child combinator and span

Tags: html, css

I have this style !

```
 div > .action{
     color: blue;
 }
```

And this code

```
    <div>
    <p class="action">
         Hey, this is a first action paragraph.
        <span> This is  a SPAN inside the action</span>
        <h3>Not a direct child, not a DIV, but a h3 block</h3>
        <div>Not a direct child but a DIV</div>
        <span> This a SPAN inside the action, AND after the closing block</span>
    </p>
    </div>
```

As a result, the first span is blue, when the h3, div and next span are black.  (tested on Chrome, IE and FF)

---

[image]

---

Is there a inline/block hidden rule ?

**EDIT** : I've put illegal elements inside the paragraph. Changing `p` with `div` makes it all blue. Thought I don't expect that, I think I should work the specs before returning there.

Comment: you miss a `div` as parent of `p` in your example.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<p>`'s can't contain either `<div>`'s nor `<h3>`'s.

Comment: @j08691 That's the answer.

Comment: Exact, I had the div in my test, put it there.Exact, an inline can't contain blocks. Now it's all blue.

Comment: Guess whatever IntelliJ is is wrong.

Comment: @j08691 I'll open a issue with this rule :)

Comment: What's the issue now? The fact that it's all blue even when the html is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By HTML syntax rules, a `p` element cannot contain an `h3` element. This rule is enforced by browsers: when they encounter an `<h3>` tag while a `p` element is open, they implicitly close the `p` element. (This implies that a `</p>` tag later is invalid and ignored.) Thus, the `p` element only contains the text that your image shows as blue.

If you fix the markup e.g. replacing the `p` element by a `div` element, things change:

```css
 div > .action{
     color: blue;
```

```html
    <div>
    <div class="action">
         Hey, this is a first action paragraph.
        <span> This is  a SPAN inside the action</span>
        <h3>Not a direct child, not a DIV, but a h3 block</h3>
        <div>Not a direct child but a DIV</div>
        <span> This a SPAN inside the action, AND after the closing block</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

All of the text inside the `div` with `class="action"` becomes blue, unless other style sheets intervene. The reason that that descendant elements inherit the text color.

Answer (score -1):

The > means a direct child of so your code reads 'select a .action class that is a direct child of a div'. take out the arrow and the whole p will be blue, Also your  inline level elements can't contain block level elements